# Shell script to reboot from different volume

Tags: command-line, automation, apfs, dual-boot, ventura

I have two installations of OSX (both Ventura) on my machine on two separate APFS volumes. I need to often switch between the two machines. I am only aware of the option to press and hold the power button during boot-up to be able to choose the machine I would like to boot from.

**Question:** Is there a shell script I can run to make my machine restart and boot from the "other" volume? Ideally, this could be transformed into an Alfred workflow.

Comment: You can try the command `sudo bless -mount /Volumes/Boot_Volume -setBoot` to set the startup volume then `sudo reboot` to restart.  I don’t have this config so I can’t test and thus I didn’t write as an answer.

Comment: Rahul: Are you aware that you can select the startup disk from System Settings application?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for the reminder. Yes I am aware, but it's too many clicks. I need a "simpler and quicker" solution since I have to switch between volumes often.

Comment: @Allan Thanks! Will test it out and share the outcome here.

Comment: It goes to say....make sure you have a backup before doing things like this.  This modifies your boot volume and even if you enter the right command, the possibility of error will always be there.

Comment: @Allan Your suggestion worked charmingly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the command suggested in comments and it worked.

```
sudo bless -mount /Volumes/Boot_Volume -setBoot
```

From there I can create a Bash/Zsh script, function or alias that I can call that will set my boot volume quickly.